# CMake Pkg-Config Library Link Path

Tags: linker, cmake, pkg-config

So I'm compiling the examples for libgstreamermm-0.10, and I've run into an issue with CMake.

With the version of libgstreamermm-0.10 that is installed by default on my system, the example segfaults.  OK, so I got the latest sources and installed them to /usr/local and get the new example.  Everything's looking good.

```
g++ main.cc player_window.cc -o test `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0` `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamermm-0.10`
```

works fine and as expected.  Great, now to try and get it to play nicely with CMake.  I make a quick CMakeLists.txt file.  I use pkg-config, as that worked fine and I don't really want to add a find module.  So my file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6.2)
project(media_player_gtkmm)

INCLUDE(FindPkgConfig)

set(SOURCES main.cc player_window.cc)

add_executable(media_player_gtkmm ${SOURCES})

#dependencies
pkg_check_modules(GSTMM REQUIRED gstreamermm-0.10)
pkg_check_modules(GTKMM REQUIRED gtkmm-3.0)
include_directories(${GTKMM_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GSTMM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTKMM_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${GSTMM_LIBRARY_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(media_player_gtkmm ${GTKMM_LIBRARIES} ${GSTMM_LIBRARIES})
```

Everything compiles until the link stage, where I get undefined symbol errors.  I then see the output of `pkg-config --libs gstreamermm-0.10` starts with -L/usr/local/lib.  I look at the output of `make VERBOSE=1` and CMake is NOT adding the -L to the link command, even though I have the link_directories line.  So even though I'm using the headers for the new version of gstreamer in /usr/local/include, the library from /usr/lib is being used instead, when I want the version in /usr/local/lib to be used.  Pkg-Config seems to pick up on this, and adjusts accordingly, but CMake, even though I have it using pkg-config internally, doesn't pick up on the link flags.

I could manually set the link flags for now, but that seems like a bit of a hack.  I'm sure there's a better way to specify this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`link_directories` only affects targets that come [AFTER it](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-April/021283.html).  So, you need 
to move your `add_executable` to be after the `link_directories` call.

Comment: I have.  I'm using the link_directories() directive, so it should add the -L?  I guess I'm misunderstanding what link_directories() does.  I could use the LDFLAGS variable, but I'm not sure how to do that and not clobber CMake's own linker flags.