# How do I change order of Libs in a cmake file?

Tags: gcc, linker, cmake, pkg-config

Link order matters. I have observed that when I compile my program with:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0` program.cpp -o program
```

which produces a number of linker errors: "undefined reference to `_gtk_init_abi_check' ", and others.  This can be remedied by specificying the input file before the libraries.

```
gcc program.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0` -o program
```

**My Question:**

How can I fix a problem of this nature when I am using a Cmake file?  Here are the contents of a simple cmake file I am currently using.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

project(program)

add_executable(program
program.cpp
)

EXEC_PROGRAM(pkg-config ARGS --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 
             OUTPUT_VARIABLE GTK2_PKG_FLAGS)
SET(GTK2_PKG_FLAGS CACHE STRING "GTK2 Flags" "${GTK2_PKG_FLAGS}")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GTK2_PKG_FLAGS}")
```

Now when I do a `cmake` followed by a `make` I get the same linker errors that the first line above gives me, so I know my linker problems are strictly related to order. So how do I change the link order when using pkg-config in a cmake file?  I've tried reordering parts of my cmake file, but I don't seem to be finding the right order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have passed both the arguments `--cflags` and `--libs` in the command which will give both -I and -L parts of the .pc file in one variable.

Try running `message("${GTK2_PKG_FLAGS}")` to print the contents.

Hence it may not be prudent to link the complete variable $GTK2_PKG_FLAGS  using target_link_libraries().

You may also want to try below steps

```
    INCLUDE(FindPkgConfig)
    pkg_check_modules(GTK REQUIRED gtk+-2.0)  

#include  
    include_directories(${GTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})  

#link  
    link_directories(${GTK_LIBRARY_DIRS})  
    target_link_libraries(program ${GTK_LIBRARIES})
```

Refer [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076820/cmake-pkg-config-library-link-path)

Comment: You even noticed my own answer and still offered improvement. This is excellent information and has clarified things for me. For some reason cmake says `Unknown CMake command "pkg_check_modules"`, but I have at least improved what I had with two seperate exec_program calls: one for --cflags and one for --libs. Then I use GTK_CFLAGS in a set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ...) command and GTK_LIBS in the target_link_libraries(...).

Comment: I have added "include" statement in the answer. That should resolve the error found. But, I had already posted the reference to another question, you should have looked there.

Answer (score 2):

Aha! After much searching around and some trial and error I finally got it to work by adding the following lines to my cmake file `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
target_link_libraries(program
${GTK2_PKG_FLAGS}
)
```

And by using some of the advice from user2618142's answer I improved it. The function pkg_check_modules() doesn't work for me for some reason. I get `Unknown CMake command "pkg_check_modules"` but by using the following as my cmake file, things work as expected.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

project(program)

exec_program(pkg-config ARGS --cflags gtk+-2.0 OUTPUT_VARIABLE GTK_FLAGS)
exec_program(pkg-config ARGS --libs   gtk+-2.0 OUTPUT_VARIABLE GTK_LIBS)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GTK_FLAGS}")

add_executable(program
program.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(program
${GTK_LIBS}
)
```

Answer (score 2):

To fix the error `Unknown CMake command "pkg_check_modules",`

Use below code at the top of CMakeLists.txt.

`find_package(PkgConfig)`

Comment: Why? Why does `find_package` introduces cmake command? (`pkg_check_modules`)